# Creating a Class for different methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I have these functions and they all working well but I want to put them into a class. For example, Class App and then pass each of them into the class as methods. Any help will really be appreciated. New python Learner.

```
def getExcel ():

    global df
    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
    df = pd.read_csv (import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 

def descriptiv(): 
    stats = df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
    stats['variance'] = df.var()
    stats['pct missing'] = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
    return stats

def correl():
    matrix = df.corr(method = 'pearson')
    return matrix
```

Comment: what do you mean by "then pass each of them into the class as methods", passing what?

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.3. A First Look at Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Classes are very easy! You can use the "self" attribute to create any other atribute in the object or call object methods.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,df):
        self.df = df
    def getExcel (self):
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
        self. df = pd.read_csv (import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 

    def descriptiv(self): 
        stats = self.df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
        stats['variance'] = df.var()
        stats['pct missing'] = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
        return stats

    def correl(self):
        matrix = self.df.corr(method = 'pearson')
        return matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following?

```
class App():
    df = None

    def getExcel ():
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
        df = pd.read_csv (import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 

    def descriptive(): 
        stats = df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
        stats['variance'] = df.var()
        stats['pct missing'] = df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
        return stats

    def correl():
        matrix = df.corr(method = 'pearson')
        return matrix
```

Then, just call `App.getExcel()`.

Or you can use Instance of you class, if you want so, use the following:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        df = None

    def getExcel (self):
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
        self.df = pd.read_csv (import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 

    def descriptive(self): 
        stats = self.df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
        stats['variance'] = self.df.var()
        stats['pct missing'] = self.df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
        return stats

    def correl(self):
        matrix = self.df.corr(method = 'pearson')
        return matrix
```

Then, to use it:

```
my_app = App()
my_app.getExcel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd
from Tkinter import filedialog

class ClassApp():
    ''' A class that do what you want '''
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def getExcel(self):
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
        self.df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path, parse_dates = date_cols, index_col = 'TimeStamp') 

    def descriptiv(self): 
        stats = self.df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
        stats['variance'] = self.df.var()
        stats['pct missing'] = self.df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100 
        return stats

    def correl(self):
        matrix = self.df.corr(method = 'pearson')
        return matrix
```

Then you have to instantiate a class, e.g

```
app = AppClass()
```

Methods are accessible e.g. :

```
app.getExcel()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are asking about:

```py
import pandas as pd
from Tkinter import filedialog
class ClassApp:
    def __init(self, df):
        self.df = df
    
    def getExcel(self):
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        date_cols = ['TimeStamp']
        self.df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path, parse_dates=date_cols, index_col='TimeStamp')
    
    def descriptiv(self):
        stats = self.df.describe([.01,.1,.9,.99]).T
        stats['variance'] = self.df.var()
        stats['pct missing'] = self.df.isna().mean().round(4) * 100
        return stats
    
    def correl(self):
        matrix = self.df.corr(method = 'pearson')
        return matrix
```

You can pass a df obj through your ClassApp and call the methods for example:

```
temp = ClassApp(df)
temp.correl()
```